# Where does Google Drive store auto backed up photos?

Tags: google-drive

I've set up photos and videos automatic backup on the Google Drive's iOS app following [these instructions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6093613?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1) and I took a photo using my iPhone to test it.

After a while I could find the picture and open it on the "Recent" tab on the website. But I don't know where it is stored (the name of the folder). I also have Google Drive installed on my mac and I couldn't find it there either.

Does anyone know where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, as I don't have Google Drive set to back up Photos, but I think you need to access them from [the Google Photos website](https://photos.google.com/) or mobile app, not from Drive.

I will do a little experimenting, but I believe this is the case.

EDIT

Yes, it appears they do not show in a folder in Drive by default. You have to enable the feature to mirror them in Drive. Otherwise, access them through Google Photos or Google+.

http://www.slashgear.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-google-drives-photos-backup-06377675/